# Piping response from a NodeJS CLI to a sudo bash command

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, sudo

Take the simple node application:

append-hosts.js

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
process.stdout.write("echo '127.0.0.1 example.com' >> /etc/hosts")
```

When running the application from the command line, I get the following output

```sh
$ chmod +x ./append-hosts.js
$ ./append-hosts.js | sudo bash
Password:
[10]  + 49783 done                   ./append-hosts.js |
        49784 suspended (tty input)  sudo bash
```

Why is my process suspending before I can enter my password?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? You typically don't want to use sudo in a shell script to begin with due to security implications involved with that. Also, why use a node shell for this, this perfectly accomplishable with old shell commands? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you do need user input from a script, there a number of ways, see this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502170/how-do-you-pipe-input-and-output-to-and-from-an-interactive-shell) for some suggestions.

Comment: @xinkecf35 My script intends to modify /etc/hosts. Rather than run the script under sudo and not let the user see whats going on under the hood, my script outputs the entire source/modification of /etc/hosts and it is up to the user to pipe it to bash to execute the hosts modification.

Comment: Personally, I would say doing it this way is unnecessary. If the user wanted to know what's happening, the user should be more than able to open the file up and inspect what the script is doing. This is in fact recommended to users so that they do not blindly curl/wget files into bash. Either way, you will need the user to interact with the script anyway, it's more work for you to setup an interactive prompt.

Comment: Second, I again don't understand why you're trying to this with a Node.Js script. If the goal is to just to automate tasks, Node, as ubiquitous as it is now, is significantly less portable than a simple bash/shell script. Why fiddle with IO redirection, when you could just have the command in a shell script, `append-host.sh` and have the user do the following: `sudo chmod +x append-host.sh && sudo ./append-host.sh`